A set inclusion equivalence in the proof of the Open Mapping Theorem
I am study the proof of the Open Mapping Theorem in Royden's Real Analysis, 4th ed., which states the following.

Let $B_X$ and $B_Y$ denote the open unit balls in $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
... the inclusion
$$
  \overline{B_Y} \cap T[X] \subset M \cdot T[\overline{B_X}].
  \tag{1}
$$
By homogeneity, this inclusion is equivalent to the existence of a constant M' for which
$$
  B_Y \cap T[X] \subset M' \cdot T[B_X].
  \tag{2}
$$

This is also the statement directly after the question from this post.
The statement of the Open Mapping Theorem is as follows:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and the linear operator $T: X \to Y$ be continuous. Then its image $T[X]$ is a closed subspace of $Y$ if and only if the operator $T$ is open.

I can see why $(1) \implies (2)$, as
$$
  B_Y \cap T[X] \subset \overline{B_Y} \cap T[X] 
  \subset M \cdot T[\overline{B_X}]
  \subset M \cdot T[2B_X]
  = 2 M \cdot T[B_X]
  =: M' \cdot T[B_X].
$$
But I cannot prove the reverse. Usually one assumes $y \in \overline{B_Y} \cap T[X]$,
so that there is ${x_n} \subset M \cdot B_X$ for which $T(x_n) \to y$.
If one can use compactness on $\overline{M B_X}$ then it just follows from taking subsequence. Yet, it is not assumed that $\overline{B_X}$ is compact, so this does not work.
Any help is appreciated.

The same strategy you use to show that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ works for $(2)$ implies (1):
If you have $(2)$, then
$$
(\frac{1}{2}\bar{B}_Y)\cap T[X] \subseteq B_Y\cap T[X]\subseteq M'.T[B_X]\subseteq M'.T[\bar{B}_X]
$$
Since $T[X]$ is invariant under scaling, $2.(\frac{1}{2}\bar{B}_Y\cap T[X]) = \bar{B}_Y\cap T[X]$, and hence
$$
\bar{B}_Y \cap T[X] \subseteq (2M').T[\bar{B}_X]
$$

That's right. I totally didn't see that. Thank you very much.

You're welcome!
